# How do I delete an element in a list and replace it to a different place in the same list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm

I am currently working on an algorithm. According to this algorithm there are folders and files. I intend to move a file with given id to a folder with given id. I'm having a hard time setting up this algorithmic structure. How can I set up this algorithm? For example;

### Acceptance criteria

Imagine an array that contains folders. These folders can have files in it. `move` function moves a file to another folder and returns the new state of given list.

#### Example list

```
const list = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Folder 1',
    files: [
      { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
      { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
      { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
      { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Folder 2',
    files: [{ id: '7', name: 'File 5' }],
  },
]
```

If I run `move(list, '4', '6')` then I expect file with id `4` moved to the folder which has id `6`. Function should return the new state below;

```
const result = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Folder 1',
    files: [
      { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
      { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
      { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Folder 2',
    files: [
      { id: '7', name: 'File 5' },
      { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
    ],
  },
];
```

I need to run the logic inside this function.

````
export default function move(list: List, source: string, destination: string): List {
 
  return list;
}```
````

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Comment: can folders be nested and are `id`'s unique across all elements?

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes, all folder id's are unique. I need help that algorithm because this is my first typescript task and I don't know about typescript syntax

Comment: This data structure is not optimal for such actions. Is it set in stone that you use this data structure?

Comment: Unfortunately, these are the constraints given to me and I don't know how to access the files field in the list, delete the data whose id is given and replace it to a different place. Please can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure is not ideal for such operations, as it is not indexed. There is no other way than to search the whole tree structure for a given id. It would have been better if every id were mapped to the corresponding location in the tree.

But given that it is like it is, you would need a function to *find* the location of a given id. That function would then return the array in which that object resides, and at which index in that array. This allows the caller to use that information for several purposes, including removal.

Here is a possible implementation and a run of the example you have given:

```js
function findItem(list, id) {
    const i = list.findIndex(child => child.id === id);
    if (i > -1) return [list, i];
    for (const {files} of list) {
        if (!files) continue;
        const result = findItem(files, id);
        if (result) return result;
    }
}

function removeItem(list, id) {
    const found = findItem(list, id);
    return found && found[0].splice(found[1], 1)[0];
}

function move(list, sourceId, targetId) {
    const found = findItem(list, targetId);
    if (!found) return;
    const removed = removeItem(list, sourceId);
    if (!removed) return;
    (found[0][found[1]].files ??= []).push(removed);
}

// Example tree as given in question
const list = [{id: '1',name: 'Folder 1',files: [{ id: '2', name: 'File 1' },{ id: '3', name: 'File 2' },{ id: '4', name: 'File 3' },{ id: '5', name: 'File 4' },],},{id: '6',name: 'Folder 2',files: [{ id: '7', name: 'File 5' }],},];

move(list, '4', '6');
console.log(list);
```

### Remarks:

If the target of the move is an object without `files` property, that `files` property is created. If you don't want this to happen, but instead want to abort the operation, then replace this line:

```
    if (!found) return;
```

With:

```
    if (!found?.files) return;
```

Your function signature of `move` expects it to return the list, but as this function will mutate the given structure, this might not be really necessary -- it would be the same list that was passed as argument.